# Replace value from updated dataset based on number of instances it appears in a second dataset

Tags: r

I have a simple 2-column dataset containing variable `cluster_size` and `index`. Originally all values of `index` were assigned a value `1`. Subsequently, I received a second dataset containing only a few clusters where `index` should updated with different integer values.

I simply need to replace the index value from the updated dataset. My specific issue is that the values for `cluster_size` can repeat multiple times, but I only need to replace it for the number of instances it appears in the updated dataset. For instance, in the example data below, the `cluster_size` value of `34` appears three times, but only once in the updated data with an `index` of 6. This means that only one of these three rows should update to 6 (doesn't matter which one).

Code to recreate a 20-row sample of the original data (`have`), updated subset (`updated`), and desired dataset (`want`) are below. The actual data has tens of thousands of rows. Ive tried several merge and loop functions (all too pathetic to waste your time by posting here), but cant seem to find an elegant solution.

```
# Data with original index cases
set.seed(03151813)
have <- data.frame(clust_size=sample(1:50,20,replace=TRUE),index=rep(1,times=20))
have <- have[order(have$clust_size),]

# Updated data only contains clusters that need updating of inde
updated <- data.frame(clust_size=c(30,34,42,44,44,46),
                      index=c(2,6,4,8,9,4))
# Desired dataset
want <- data.frame(clust_size=have$clust_size,
                   index=c(rep(1,times=9),2,1,6,
                   1,1,1,4,1,8,9,4))
```

Comment: Doesn't look like cluster_size is unique. How do you intend to match 44 with 8 and 44 also with index = 9?

Comment: This highlights my coding issue - in these sample data, the original dataset has two repetitions of 44. The updated dataset indicates that `index` should be replaced with 8 in one of the two instances, and 9 in the other. The final output would have two 44's, one with 8 and one with 9 (order doesn't matter). Note that if there were three 44's in the original data, however, then one should have an `index` value of 8, one should have 9, and the other should remain at 1 since there are only two instances of 44 in the updated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach. Add row numbers to `have` and `updated` for each `clust_size`. So the `clust_size` of 34 will have rows numbered consecutively 1, 2, and 3.

Then, you can `merge` the two together on both `clust_size` and row number. If you include `all.x` you will get all rows from the first data frame `have`.

Final step is to replace the missing `NA` values in your new index column with the original index.

```
have$rn <- with(have, ave(seq_along(clust_size), clust_size, FUN = seq_along))
updated$rn <- with(updated, ave(seq_along(clust_size), clust_size, FUN = seq_along))
want <- merge(have, updated, all.x = TRUE, by = c("clust_size", "rn"))
want$index.y <- ifelse(is.na(want$index.y), want$index.x, want$index.y)
want[, c("clust_size", "index.y")]
```

An alternate version using `dplyr` would be something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

have2 <- have %>%
  group_by(clust_size) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number())

updated2 <- updated %>%
  group_by(clust_size) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number())
  
left_join(have2, updated2, by = c("clust_size", "rn")) %>%
  mutate(index.y = coalesce(index.y, index.x))
```

**Output**

```
   clust_size index.y
1           1       1
2           5       1
3           8       1
4          10       1
5          16       1
6          20       1
7          22       1
8          27       1
9          29       1
10         30       2
11         30       1
12         34       6
13         34       1
14         34       1
15         35       1
16         42       4
17         43       1
18         44       8
19         44       9
20         46       4
```